# Extjs 6.0 RadioButton Column

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button, extjs6

I have a really specific case which i need 5 distinct columns on a datagrid and which one of them has a single radiobutton.

Since on ExtJS i didn't found any "radiocolumn" element, i created it myself, and goes something like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.column.RadioColumn', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn',

alternateClassName: 'Ext.ux.RadioColumn',

alias: 'widget.radiocolumn',

groupField: undefined,

allowUncheck: false,

renderer : function(value, meta) {

    var classer = "PROBLEM_UNCHECKED";

    meta.innerCls = "";
    if (this.disabled) {
        meta.tdCls += ' ' + this.disabledCls;
    }
    if (value) {
        classer = "PROBLEM_CHECKED";
    }

    return "<span  class='"+ classer + "' role='button' tabIndex='0'></span>";
},
```

So my problem is, as you can see my Classer values are "PROBLEM_CHECKED" and "PROBLEM_UNCHECKED" instead of their real class values. I've searched for all the ext and online and i couldn't find the default class value for radiobuttons (that ext generally uses), even with the inpsect element, the class that this element retrives doesn't match the regular radiobutton one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ExtJS have ['widgetcolumn'](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html) component you can use this.

A widget column is configured with a widget config object which specifies an xtype to indicate which type of Widget or Component belongs in the cells of this column.

I have created an [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27os) demo. It will show how is working. Hope this will help you.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', {
        name: 'checked',
        type: 'boolean',
        defaultValue: true
    }],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }, {
        text: 'Status',
        width: 150,
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'checked',
        onWidgetAttach: function (column, widget, record) {
            widget.down(`[inputValue=${record.get('checked')}]`).setValue(true);
        },
        widget: {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Yes',
                inputValue: true
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'No',
                inputValue: false
            }]
        }
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xtype `widgetcolumn` to add a Radio Button to a grid column. [Here's](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/288d) a small example for demonstration.